# Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a Fahrenheit temperature into Celsius.
doing the following I'm always getting zero:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Celcius_Farenheit_Converter
{
class Program
{

    static double Celcius(double f)
    {
        double c = 5/9*(f - 32);

        return c;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "enter a farenheit tempature";
        double c = Celcius(GetTempature(text));
        Console.WriteLine("the tempature in Celicus is {0}", c);

        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }

    static double GetTempature(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        bool IsItTemp = false;
        double x = 0;

        do
        {
            IsItTemp = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
        } while (!IsItTemp);

        return x;

    }
}
}
```

can you help me fix it?

Comment: Instead of passing temperatures about in numeric variables, why not use a struct to define a temperature type.  There's a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995920/using-real-world-units-instead-of-types.  That will make your code simpler to maintain in the long run, as well as improving the readability.

Answer (score 33):

`5/9` performs an integer division—that is, it always discards the fractional part—so it will always return 0.

`5.0/9.0` performs floating-point division, and will return the expected 0.55555...

Try this instead:

```
static double Celcius(double f)
{
    double c = 5.0/9.0 * (f - 32);

    return c;
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [/ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

Comment: It should Be sufficient to write it like this:5/9f * (f - 32) in other words, you only have to specify that one operand is a floating point variable

Comment: Technically you should have a guard to prevent c going below −273.15, or at least throw an exception.

Comment: @Moop Unless you're trying to represent a temperature *difference* larger than 273.15° C or a [temperature below 0° K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature)--which isn't entirely unheard of. In both cases the input to this function would be less than -459.67° F, so one would assume that was the actual intent.

Comment: @pswg I'll give you the difference, not the below 0 Kelvin

Comment: I'd recommend to always do the division last in floating point math. It reduces and round-off errors. So `5*(f-32)/9` would work just fine, with implicit conversion from `int` to `float`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Nope; Moop was correct the first time. If one is converting delta-temperatures from F to C then the formula is simply deltaF = 9.0 / 5.0 * deltaC, with no 32 degree offset. Your formula only applies to measures of temperature points, not deltas.

Answer (score 12):

Change your *integer division* to *floating point division* like;

```
double c = (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);
```

From [`C# Specification $7.7.2 Division operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-);

> ###Integer division:

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
> the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
> absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
> or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
> negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

As Frederik *[said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542357/convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius-in-c-sharp#comment27274305_18542376)*, only chaning one of your variables to floating point type is also enough for your calculation. (`5 / 9f` or `5f / 9` gives the right solution)

Comment: I can see absolutely nothing wrong with this answer; I'd like to know why it was downvoted, too.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier in the comments I suggested the option of using a `struct` to encapsulate your temperature conversion logic.  I've knocked up a rough hash below (only partially tested) should it be of interest:

```
public struct Temperature: IComparable
{
    #region fields
    double value;
    TemperatureUnit unit;
    #endregion fields
    #region constructors
    public Temperature(double value, TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        AssertUnitNotNull(unit);
        AssertValueNotBelowAbsZero(value, unit);
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    public Temperature(Temperature temp, TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        AssertUnitNotNull(unit);
        this.value = ConvertUnit(temp.value, temp.unit, unit);
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    #endregion constructors
    #region properties
    public double Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set 
        {
            AssertValueNotBelowAbsZero(value, this.unit);
            this.value = value; 
        }
    }
    public TemperatureUnit Unit
    {
        get { return this.unit; }
        set 
        {
            AssertUnitNotNull(value);
            if (this.unit != value)
            {
                this.value = ConvertUnit(this.value, this.unit, value);
                this.unit = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion properties
    #region methods
    #region overridden methods
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.CompareTo(obj) == 0;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.unit.ToKelvin(value).GetHashCode();
    }
    const string OutputFormat = "{0}{1}";
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(OutputFormat, this.value, this.unit.Symbol);
    }
    #endregion overridden methods
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Temperature? t = obj as Temperature?;
        if (!t.HasValue) return -1;
        return this.unit.ToKelvin(value).CompareTo(t.Value.unit.ToKelvin(t.Value.value));   
    }
    #region operator overloads
    public static Temperature operator +(Temperature a, double b)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value + b, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator +(Temperature a, Temperature b)
    {
        return a + ConvertUnit(b.value, b.unit, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator +(Temperature a, TemperatureUnit b)
    {
        return new Temperature(a, b);
    }
    public static Temperature operator -(Temperature a, double b)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value - b, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator -(Temperature a, Temperature b)
    {
        return a - ConvertUnit(b.value, b.unit, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator ++(Temperature a)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value + 1.0, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator --(Temperature a)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value - 1.0, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator /(Temperature a, double b)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value / b, a.unit);
    }
    public static Temperature operator *(Temperature a, double b)
    {
        return new Temperature(a.value * b, a.unit);
    }
    #endregion operator overloads
    #region helper methods
    private static double ConvertUnit(double value, TemperatureUnit from, TemperatureUnit to)
    {
        return to.FromKelvin(from.ToKelvin(value));
    }
    #endregion helper methods
    #endregion methods
    #region static validation methods
    private static void AssertUnitNotNull(TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        if (unit == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    private static void AssertValueNotBelowAbsZero(double value, TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        if (unit.ToKelvin(value) < 0.0) throw new TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException(value,unit);
    }
    #endregion static validation methods

}

public sealed class TemperatureUnit
{
    #region delegate definitions
    delegate double Conversion(double source);
    #endregion delegate definitions

    #region attributes
    readonly string name;
    readonly string symbol;
    //base all functions around Kelvin since that allows us to restrict values to zero and above
    readonly Conversion fromKelvin;
    readonly Conversion toKelvin;
    #endregion attributes

    #region constructors
    private TemperatureUnit(string name, string symbol, Conversion fromKelvin, Conversion toKelvin)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.fromKelvin = fromKelvin;
        this.toKelvin = toKelvin;
    }
    #endregion constructors

    #region properties
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
    public string Symbol { get { return this.symbol; } }
    #region defined units
    public static TemperatureUnit Kelvin = new TemperatureUnit("Kelvin", "\u212A", delegate(double d) { return d; }, delegate(double d) { return d; });
    public static TemperatureUnit Celcius = new TemperatureUnit("Celcius", "\u2103", KelvinToCelcius, CelciusToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Farenheit = new TemperatureUnit("Farenheit", "\u2109", KelvinToFarenheit, FarenheitToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Rankine = new TemperatureUnit("Rankine", "\u00B0Ra", KelvinToRankine, RankineToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Romer = new TemperatureUnit("R\u03B8mer", "\u00B0R\u03B8", KelvinToRomer, RomerToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Newton = new TemperatureUnit("Newton", "\u00B0N", KelvinToNewton, NewtonToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Delisle = new TemperatureUnit("Delisle", "\u00B0D", KelvinToDelisle, DelisleToKelvin);
    public static TemperatureUnit Reaumur = new TemperatureUnit("R\u00E9amur", "\u00B0R\u00E9", KelvinToReaumur, ReaumurToKelvin);
    #endregion defined units
    #endregion properties

    #region functions
    public double FromKelvin(double kelvin)
    {
        return this.fromKelvin(kelvin);
    }
    public double ToKelvin(double value)
    {
        return this.toKelvin(value);
    }
    #endregion functions

    #region overridden methods
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        TemperatureUnit tu = obj as TemperatureUnit;
        if (tu == null) return false;
        return this.name.Equals(tu.name);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.name.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name.ToString();
    }
    #endregion overridden methods

    #region static conversion functions
    #region Celcius
    const double KelvinToCelciusOffset = -273.15;
    public static double CelciusToKelvin(double celcius)
    {
        return celcius - KelvinToCelciusOffset;
    }
    public static double KelvinToCelcius(double kelvin)
    {
        return kelvin + KelvinToCelciusOffset;
    }
    #endregion Celcius
    #region Fahrenheit
    //Fahrenheit    [°F] = [K] × 9⁄5 − 459.67   [K] = ([°F] + 459.67) × 5⁄9
    const double KelvinToFarenheitMultiplier = 9.0 / 5.0;
    const double KelvinToFarenheitOffset = -459.67;
    public static double FarenheitToKelvin(double farenheit)
    {
        return (farenheit - KelvinToFarenheitOffset) / KelvinToFarenheitMultiplier;
    }
    public static double KelvinToFarenheit(double kelvin)
    {
        return kelvin * KelvinToFarenheitMultiplier + KelvinToFarenheitOffset;
    }
    #endregion Fahrenheit
    #region Rankine
    const double KelvinToRankineMultiplier = KelvinToFarenheitMultiplier;
    public static double RankineToKelvin(double rankine)
    {
        return rankine / KelvinToRankineMultiplier;
    }
    public static double KelvinToRankine(double kelvin)
    {
        return kelvin * KelvinToRankineMultiplier;
    }
    #endregion Rankine
    #region Romer
    //[K] = ([°Rø] − 7.5) × 40⁄21 + 273.15  [°Rø] = ([K] − 273.15) × 21⁄40 + 7.5
    const double KelvinToRomerMultiplier = 21.0 / 40.0;
    const double KelvinToRomerOffset1 = KelvinToCelciusOffset;
    const double KelvinToRomerOffset2 = 7.5;
    public static double RomerToKelvin(double romer)
    {
        return (romer - KelvinToRomerOffset2) / KelvinToRomerMultiplier - KelvinToRomerOffset1;
    }
    public static double KelvinToRomer(double kelvin)
    {
        return (kelvin + KelvinToRomerOffset1) * KelvinToRomerMultiplier + KelvinToRomerOffset2;
    }
    #endregion Romer
    #region Newton
    //[K] = [°N] × 100⁄33 + 273.15  [°N] = ([K] − 273.15) × 33⁄100
    const double KelvinToNewtonMultiplier = 33.0 / 100.0;
    const double KelvinToNewtonOffset = KelvinToCelciusOffset;
    public static double NewtonToKelvin(double newton)
    {
        return (newton / KelvinToNewtonMultiplier) - KelvinToNewtonOffset;
    }
    public static double KelvinToNewton(double kelvin)
    {
        return (kelvin + KelvinToNewtonOffset) * KelvinToNewtonMultiplier;
    }
    #endregion Newton
    #region Delisle
    //[K] = 373.15 − [°De] × 2⁄3    [°De] = (373.15 − [K]) × 3⁄2
    const double KelvinToDelisleMultiplier = 1.5;
    const double KelvinToDelisleOffset = 373.15;
    public static double DelisleToKelvin(double delisle)
    {
        return KelvinToDelisleOffset - delisle / KelvinToDelisleMultiplier;
    }
    public static double KelvinToDelisle(double kelvin)
    {
        return (KelvinToDelisleOffset - kelvin) * KelvinToDelisleMultiplier;
    }
    #endregion Delisle
    #region Reaumur
    //[K] = [°Ré] × 5⁄4 + 273.15    [°Ré] = ([K] − 273.15) × 4⁄5
    const double KelvinToReaumurMultiplier = 4.0 / 5.0;
    const double KelvinToReaumurOffset = KelvinToCelciusOffset;
    public static double ReaumurToKelvin(double reaumur)
    {
        return reaumur / KelvinToReaumurMultiplier - KelvinToReaumurOffset;
    }
    public static double KelvinToReaumur(double kelvin)
    {
        return (kelvin + KelvinToReaumurOffset) * KelvinToReaumurMultiplier;
    }
    #endregion Reaumur
    #endregion static conversion functions

}

public class TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException : Exception
{
    public TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException() : base() { }
    public TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message,innerException) { }
    public TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info,context) { }

    const string ErrorMessageFormat = "Value '{0}{1}' is below absolute zero!";
    public TemperatureIsBelowAbsoluteZeroException(double value, TemperatureUnit unit) : base(string.Format(ErrorMessageFormat, value, unit.Symbol)) { }
}
```

Comment: I don't really think this is appropriate. OP is obviously just starting out, probably a bit complicated.

Comment: Also, negative Kelvin temperatures hypothetically exist, you just need to skip absolute 0.0000... when reducing the temperature

Comment: @Kroltan Good knowledge, thanks: http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-gas-goes-below-absolute-zero-1.12146

Comment: This is the finest example of exceeding expectations Ive ever witnessed on SO!

Comment: NB: Fans of the Chicken (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken) programming language may wish to restrict the units to Kelvin, Fahrenheit and Celcius.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TempConvert
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Variables declared to hold and test conversion
            //floats used to avoid int calculation errors
            float originalFarenheit;
            float centigrade;
            float returnFarenheit;

            Console.Write("Enter Temperature (Farenheit): ");      //take temp to be converted
            originalFarenheit = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());   //hold as float var
            centigrade = ((originalFarenheit - 32) / 9) * 5;       //Convert to centrigrade
            returnFarenheit = ((centigrade / 5) * 9) + 32;         //test conversion by reversing

            Console.WriteLine("Centigrade = :" + centigrade);              //Display result
            Console.WriteLine("Return Farenheit = :" + returnFarenheit);   //Test result

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does get around the floating point problem; I don't see it as adding anything to the other answers. Its also non-obvious *why* this works (all division ops have a `float` operand), so it at *least* needs an accompanying explanation.

Comment: Yeah, you are right - it does need comments. I just thought it was a bit simpler than some of the other answers and seeing as I had just done this assignment when signing up I thought I would post.

Comment: +1 for effort; I would put an explanation above that notes this works because your variables are of type `float`, not `int` and that you cleverly paired your operators so you never had an `int`/`int`.

Comment: Thanks, by no means exhaustive and there are omissions in regards to incorrect input etc.. but a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general method, which will perform all temperature unit conversions

```
public static double ConvertTemperatureUnits(TemperatureUnit toConvert, TemperatureUnit from, double value)
    {
        double convertedValue = 0.0;

        if (toConvert == from)
            return value;

        switch (toConvert)
        {
            case TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT:
                {
                    switch (from)
                    {
                        case TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS:
                            convertedValue = (value * 9) / 5 + 32;
                            break;
                        case TemperatureUnit.KELVIN:
                            convertedValue = 1.8 * (value - 273.15) + 32;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TemperatureUnit.KELVIN:
                switch (from)
                {
                    case TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS:
                        convertedValue = value + 273.15;
                        break;
                    case TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT:
                        convertedValue = (value + 459.67) * 5 / 9;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS:
                switch (from)
                {
                    case TemperatureUnit.KELVIN:
                        convertedValue = value - 273.15;
                        break;
                    case TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT:
                        convertedValue = (value - 32) * 5 / 9;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return convertedValue;
    }
```

create TemperatureUnit enum like this

```
   enum TemperatureUnit
{
    FAHRENHEIT,
    KELVIN,
    CELSIUS
}
```