# Convert Fahrenheit to Celcius in C# with methods

Tags: c#, methods

Hello guys I am a newbie and I am currently a first year in Computer Science. We have been given an exercise in which we have to convert from Fahrenheit to Celcius with methods (professor advised no static). We have started with C#. Here is my code.

```
namespace Week3_Exe3._1{
public class Formula
{
    public double F;
    public double C;

    public void calculate(double F, double C)
    {
        C = (5 / 9) * (F - 32);

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Fahrenheit you wish to convert");
        F = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Formula form = new Formula();

        Console.WriteLine(F + "Fahrenheit correspond to " + form.calculate() + "Degrees celcius");
    }
}
}
```

I am currently working with Visual Studio Community 2015 and in form.calculate, it reds out the calculate with the error

> CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter '' of 'Formula.calculate(double, double)'

I searched for it but I still do not understand what is missing. I created an instance to use, but it's not working. Can anyone give me answer?

Comment: Your `calculate` method expect 2 parameters but you didn't send them. That's strange because it shouldn't take 2 parameter. Just one enough.

Comment: Not to mention the calculate method returns void.

Comment: also it seems to me that you are trying to use your public fields in your calculation and that you want them to be auto passed to your method, but you try to pass them within the method signature.

Comment: Please check following answer posted by me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542357/convert-from-fahrenheit-to-celsius/48547880#48547880

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `calculate` method expect `2` parameters but you try to call it without parameters. In my humble opinion, it shouldn't take two parameters *at all*. Just one fahrenheit parameter is enough so it can calculate celsius value.

Also `5 / 9` performs an [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) —it *always* discards the fractional part— so it will always return `0`.

A static method should be enough for your case;

```
static double Celsius(double f)
{
    return 5.0/9.0 * (f - 32);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There a few errors in  your code. First of all, your function only requires one input parameter, the temperature in Fahrenheit. After you have resolved this, you will find temperature of 100 Fahrenheit will return a temperature of 0 Celcius and this is obviously not correct. You need to modify your equation to use at least one fractional part otherwise C# will implicitly cast the values to integers.

```
using System;

namespace Week3_Exe3._1
{
    public class Formula
    {
        public double calculate(double F)
        {
            return (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32.0);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Fahrenheit you wish to convert");
            var F = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Formula form = new Formula();
            Console.WriteLine(F + " Fahrenheit correspond to " + form.calculate(F) + " Degrees celcius");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few holes, my suggested rewrite is this:

```
public class Formula
{
    public double F;
    public double C;

    public void calculate()
    {
        C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Fahrenheit you wish to convert");
        Formula form = new Formula();
        form.F = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        form.calculate();
        Console.WriteLine(F + "Fahrenheit correspond to " + form.C + "Degrees celcius");
    }
}
```

keep in mind that this code only works for F => C, not the other way around.

Comment: `5 / 9` always return `0`. Change it to floating-point division.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is not going to be much use to you unless you understand what parameters and return values are and how to use them.

In your definition of the calculate method

```
public void calculate(double F, double C)
```

the method is expecting two input parameters, F and C. This means when you call the method from your main method, you need to pass in two values between the parentheses:

```
form.calculate(F, C)
```

As others have pointed out, you really only need one parameter, for the Farenheight. Which brings us to the next bit - how do you get a value back for C? This is what return values are for. That little word in between `public` and `calculate` defines the return type for your method. `void` means nothing is returned. In your case you'll be wanting to return a `double`. So putting this together the method definition should look like this

```
public double calculate(double F)
```

Finally you must actually return the value at the end of your method:

```
double C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32);
return C;
```

Comment: `5 / 9` always return `0`. Change it to floating-point division

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't the focus of my answer but I should have still modified the formula since I was including that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

As you already assign the value of `C` you can remove `C` parameter from your function defenition code. Than your function must be like.

```
public void calculate(double F)
{
    C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32.0);  
}
```

Than in your code

```
public class Formula
{
    // public double F; remove because F is used as parameter
    public double C;

    public void calculate(double F)
    {
        C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32.0);    
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Fahrenheit you wish to convert");
        var   F = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Creating new variable

        Formula form = new Formula();

        form.calculate(F); // Pass parameter to our function

        Console.WriteLine(F + "Fahrenheit correspond to " + form.C /* retrive the results of calculation */ + "Degrees celcius"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `5 / 9` always return `0`. Change it to floating-point division.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Thank you! I didn't see that