# Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius with a scroll bar c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a scroll bar that will convert the input from Celsius into  Fahrenheit. I am having trouble with the maths for the conversion:

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    decimal x = 1.8m;
    int y = 32;
    int z = vScrollBar1.Value;
    label2.Text = (z. * x + y);
    label1.Text = vScrollBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `label2.Text = (z * x + y).ToString("F1");` - let have 1 digit after the decimal point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542357/convert-from-fahrenheit-to-celsius)

Answer (score 4):

Compute the value

```
 C = (F - 32) / 9 * 5
```

and then represent it with the desired *format*:

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
  var F = vScrollBar1.Value;   
  var C = (F - 32.0) / 9.0 * 5.0;

  label1.Text = F.ToString();
  // "F1" - let have 1 digit after the decimal point
  label2.Text = C.ToString("F1"); 
}
```