# What should I store Weights in?

Tags: c#, enums

I have some Weights(ounces, grams and etc) but not sure how I should handle them. At first I was going to use an Enum and give each one an integer value and then store that value in my database(using EF)

I thought this would be a good idea as then I can do checks like

```
if(Measurement.Grams == usersChoice)
{
  // do something
}
```

It would also restrict the choices(ie if I don't support "stones" then it will fail if I try to set that in the enum),

I was going to then convert the Enums to an array and display it to the user but I ran into one problem "Fluid Ounce". I would have to display it as "FluidOunce".

I could use the Description Property but now I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

Comment: Why are you not creating a class? A property for the value, one for the name.

Comment: Would this class be mapped to a database table?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348853/units-of-measure-in-c-sharp-almost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Use `enum Measurement` and `Dictionary<Measurement, string>` to map from `Measurement` to the display name.

```
public enum Measurement
{
    Grams,
    FluidOunces,
    ...
}

private static Dictionary<Measurement, string> displayName = new Dictionary<Measurement, string>
{
    { Measurement.Grams, "Grams" },
    { Measurement.FluidOunces, "Fluid Ounces" },
    ...
};

public static string DisplayName(Measurement measurement)
{
    return displayName[measurement];
}
```

## Option 2

Use `class Measurement` that has no public constructor, has `public static readonly` instances, and has properties.

```
public class Measurement
{
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    private Measurement(string displayName)
    {
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
    }
    public static readonly Measurement Grams = new Measurement("Grams");
    public static readonly Measurement FluidOunces = new Measurement("Fluid Ounces");
    ...
}
```