# c# native type for bytes equivalent to System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit

Tags: c#

Is there an equivalent type for **Bytes**, just like `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit` for units?

I imagine a struct which takes the byte count as long and two calculated properties:

- enumeration type with the highest multiple >= 1 (B, KB, MB, etc..)
- decimal with the value in the above multiple

Implementing such struct is far from difficult but i'd rather use something from the framework

Below i paste a sample to better explain my intent

*my draft proposal*

```
public struct ByteUnit
{
   public long ByteCount {get; set; }
   public ByteMultiple Multiple {get; }
   public decimal ByteCountInMultiple {get; }
}
```

Is there a framework type for such a thing?

Or doesn't it even make any sense and i am missing the big picture?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: i'm trying to find out if there is already something like this in the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such type in .Net Framework and unlikely to have one (in part due to controversial nature of M/K multipliers - there are at least 3 meaning for it: programmers, SI and marketing).

You may look into 2 other approaches:

- separate presentation of data. I.e. you can have custom formatting options for you type (type contains just data like `12333 bytes`) and than format `String.Format("M as custom format - {0:M}", valueOfMyType)`
- check out other questions on "units of measurement" topic (see results of [C# unit measurment](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+unit+measurment)  search here like [Units of measure in C# - almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348853/units-of-measure-in-c-sharp-almost)). Also see how it is done in F# for more inspirations. This approach may be useful if you have many similar values with "unit of measurement" like mass, speed, volume, temperature.

Comment: Thanks. From what i understood you're saying to implement a IFormattable class with the presentation logic, is that it?

Comment: @LuisFilipe - yes - to me it looks like your goal is just formatting. I can't imagine why data portion of "byte count" would behave differently unlike in `Unit` case where something like "percentage" and "pixels" would mean very different thing on data level.