# How to create type-safe numerical types?

Tags: c#, types

## Context

Suppose I'm writing an app about cakes.
I need to store the weight of cakes in kg and their FCR (frosting/chocolate ratio. I made that up). I can store these values as `float`. The problem I see with that is that *I can assign a weight-in-kg value to an FCR field*.

C#'s type system can prevent errors like this. If I create a `class WeightInKg` and a `class FrostingChocolateRatio`, I won't be able to assign one to the other.

## Issue

I will then need to implement all numerical operators (`+ - * / > < ==` etc) again. These are already annoying to implement, because they are only mere wrappers over the functionality of `float`. However, as these structs are *both* based on `float`, all those wrapper methods are virtually identical. This will again be the case for every other such `float`-based type.

## What I have tried / thought about

- Good old OO inheritance. An `abstract class FloatValue` can provide all the numerical operations, but these then return the `FloatValue` type instead of the (type safe) subclass type. I also feel like a struct should be used for something that is inherently a bare-bones value, and structs don't support sub-classes.
- Generics. I am currently using this; a `struct Quantity<T>` with all the numerical operations implemented. For `T`, I then use empty "marker classes", which only exist to identify a certain type of quantity (e.g. `FrostingChocolateRatio`). This works, but constantly using `Quantity<WhatIReallyWant>` is awkward and produces more visual clutter in the code.

## Question

Is this as close as I can get to what I want, or are there cleaner ways to have such type-safe values in C#?

## Addition

As PaulF mentioned, `FrostingChocolateRatio` is not an ideal example because the math works differently for ratios. However, I'm out of creativity for today; just assume it does exactly the same as `WeightInKg`.
The point is that there are several different types of values which behave exactly like `float`, but it doesn't make sense to add a centimeter to a liter.

Comment: How is a `WeightInKg` different from a `FrostingChocolateRatio`?  They're both just `float` values underneath.  So they're not really different types, just different values.  It's like if you have a product with a name and description and you worry about them both being `string`.

Comment: You're grossly overthinking the problem, it seems. There always will be a way to interchange 2 numbers: regardless of how deep you shove them down the type hierarchy they're just numbers.

Comment: Use the [right kind of language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure) if this is important to you.

Comment: Well you do actually need to implement the numerical operators differently - adding two weights is simple enough, but adding two ratios is different => 0.8 + 0.2 = 0.5 NOT 1.0 (if the ratio 0.8 is equivalent to 8 parts frosting to 10 parts chocolate & 0.2 is equivalent to 2:10 ratio, then the sum is 10 parts frosting to 20 parts chocolate)

Comment: @juharr Yes, they are both just `float` values underneath. However, when you're asking "_How is a WeightInKg different from a FrostingChocolateRatio_", then you must not have eaten a lot of cake in your life :D

Comment: @icebat My goal is not to fight against programmers who do their best to misuse the code, but to help well-meaning programmers who just happen to [trip up on something as trivial as a typo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure).

Comment: @HansPassant Programming is my job, though. I can't just go over to my boss and tell him "_Yeah I wanna use F# now, let's put the client on hold for a couple weeks while we learn a new language and port all our code and yeah I guess let's try and find an F# 3D-Graphics engine that fulfills our needs first._" F# always seemed pretty cool to me, but it's not the answer to "how to do [x] in C#?".

Comment: @PaulF Good point! I did not think of that at all. I added a note about that.

Comment: I think you're slightly mistaking Hans' point. Units-of-measure types are not super easy to create in C#; they exist in F# because Andrew Kennedy did a huge amount of design and implementation work to get them into the F# type system. No one did that work for C#, and it is not trivial work that you can emulate easily. That said, there are things you can do; as you've discovered you can make wrapper structs or classes, and there is a lot of boring boilerplate code to write. I would write structs, not classes, but the path you're on is pretty much how you do it in a language without unit types.

Comment: If you need to do this on a shoe-string budget then apps hungarian is notable as a standard solution in languages that don't permit easily overriding value type behavior.  When you see yourself adding a kgFoo to a chocBar then you instantly know you have a bug.  Not for everybody, but Eric was a big fan :)

Comment: Indeed, if you cannot get the compiler to do it, then making typing errors apparent to humans reading the code is better than nothing. Hans is correct to point out that I am a fan of Hungarian notations which encode *semantic* information, like "this is a count of bytes" vs "this is a count of characters" vs "this is an index into a string", and so on. "System Hungarian" where you encode *what is already encoded in the type system* into the name is a pointless waste of effort that I don't understand why it became so popular.

Comment: All that said: your primary objection seems to be the amount of time you spend re-implementing operators, but who cares?  Just cut-and-paste the boilerplate code. It's only a few dozen lines of code with small changes, and the jitter will inline them away.  You'll write the code once and then never think about it again.

Comment: And finally: don't use `float`. Use `double`. Using `float` buys you basically nothing, unless you have hundreds of thousands of them in an array.  The math will all be done in doubles on the chip anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Units of measure in C# - almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348853/units-of-measure-in-c-sharp-almost)